# jQuery Mobile Field containers don't render properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to use Field containers of jQuery Mobile but [the result](http://jsfiddle.net/UNL9A/3/) doesn't look like [the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/textinputs/index.html).

Here is my code:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <form>        
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="voila" value=""  />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>​
```

If I rename the field id into 'name' or 'pass' it looks like ok: http://jsfiddle.net/UNL9A/2

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` property of your label should match the `id` of your text input. this should look nice:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
    <form>        
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="voila">Text Input:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="voila" value=""  />
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>​
```